# Lorentz transformation rules using the field strength tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

A rank 2-tensor transforms under Lorentz transformation in the following way:
$$T^{\mu \nu} \rightarrow T^{' \mu \nu} = \Lambda^\mu _\sigma\Lambda^\nu _\rho T^{\sigma \rho}$$

The field strength tensor is given by the following:
$$\Bbb{F}^{\mu \nu}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & E_x/c, & E_y/c & E_z /c \\ -E_x/c & 0 & B_z & -B_y \\ -E_y /c & -B_z & 0 & B_x \\ -E_z/c & B_y & -B_x &0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, I was looking at how the $F^{01}$ component of the this tensor would transform, here is what I got:
$$F^{'01} = \Lambda^0 _0\Lambda^1_0 F^{00} + \Lambda^0 _1\Lambda^1_0 F^{10} + \Lambda^0 _0\Lambda^1_1 F^{01} + \Lambda^0 _1\Lambda^1_1 F^{11}$$

However my lecture says it should transform in the following way:
$$F^{'01} = \Lambda^0 _0\Lambda^1_0 F^{00} + \Lambda^0 _0F^{10} + \Lambda^0 _0\Lambda^1_1 F^{01} + \Lambda^0 _1\Lambda^1_1 F^{11}$$
I am struggling to understand why my second term is wrong.

Comment: I think your lecture notes are mistaken. The expression you think should be true is obviously correct and is not the same as the expression in your lecture notes--so the latter is wrong.

Comment: Use explicit matrix multiplication, exemplified [here](https://hepweb.ucsd.edu/ph110b/110b_notes/node69.html), to figure out what's right for yourself.

Comment: Actually Einstein's summation convention includes all indices $\sigma=0,\ldots,3$, i.e. $F'^{0 1}=\sum\limits_{\sigma=0, \rho=0}^{3,3} \Lambda^0_{\sigma} \Lambda^1_{\rho}F^{\sigma\rho}$. However, one can neglect the terms which are zero due to the antisymmetry of the tensor, i.e. all  terms whose indices are equal $\sigma=\rho$. Certainly if the E-field or likewise the B-field is zero, these terms don't need to be taken neither (But this is an additional assumption). One can find compact formulas for the Lorentz transformation of the field strength tensor on Wikipedia.